# SAS and excel bit discrepancy work around

Tags: excel, sas, 32bit-64bit

Does anyone know a workaround to make excel files work in SAS when their is a bit discrepancy? My Microsoft office applications are 32 bit, and I have a downloaded version of SAS that I got for free while in school.  The problem is that the SAS is 64 bit, and doesn't work with excel files.  Is there an easy way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have SAS 9.4 then you can read and write XLS and XLSX file directly.
Use PROC IMPORT.

```
proc import datafile='myfile.xlsx' out=mydataset dbms=xlsx ....
```

Or even a libname.

```
libname mydata xlsx 'myfile.xlsx'; 
proc copy inlib=mydata outlib=work; run;
```

Comment: Thanks it works for the most part. For some reason though some commands don't seem to work like they should. Like specifying the range of cells in the proc import step doesn't seem to actually change the range of data that is pulled in.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version not all features of XLSX are supported. You can download PCFileServer to get around these and use DBMS=EXCELCS. You also have the option of using SAS University Edition for free. Both should be under similar licence, only valid for learning purposes.